# Upload from csv file to GAE-Java datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I upload a CSV file to a GAE-Java datastore? Earlier questions were about data upload using Python. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @user2266449 no code yet.  still in data transformation stage.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is you can't GAE Doesn't have any option to import from custom CSV files

But using the GAE admin console, you can export or import datastore entities, if that is what you want then you can check out the app engine datastore admin console

To upload an custom CSV content to GAE datastore , you need to write servlet endpoint to receive the file, process the CSV, manually create and save entities , which can be done in TASK QUEUE if content is high and takes long time

Comment: is there a tutorial on appcfg, the python alternative?